# sorting hashes, 4 digit number causing issues

Tags: ruby

I am sorting an array filled with hashes using the code below:

```
array.sort_by {|hash| hash[:key_name]}
```

When I sort by `array[:damagemin]` all the numbers are sorted except the lone 4-digit number which is being sorted as if it is a "1":

```html
array
=> [{:heroname=>"Bastion", :winrate=>"53.6%", :damagemin=>"1079", :herokd=>"2.23:1"},
 {:heroname=>"Lúcio", :winrate=>"57.6%", :damagemin=>"328", :herokd=>"1.51:1"},
 {:heroname=>"Mei", :winrate=>"51%", :damagemin=>"451", :herokd=>"1.95:1"},
 {:heroname=>"Reinhardt", :winrate=>"51.3%", :damagemin=>"463", :herokd=>"1.28:1"}]
```

How can I resolve this issue and sort the numbers from highest to lowest regardless of their length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `damagemin` are strings and strings sorting algorithm  is different from numbers sorting algorithm. Strings sorting doesn't account for length of the word (remember words order in a dictionary).

For example, `'1234' > '456' => false`

To solve your problem, you can say:

```
array.sort_by { |hash| -hash[:damagemin].to_i }
```

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, I missed that line.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what need to happen!

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
array = [
         { :heroname=>"Bastion", :winrate=>"53.6%", :damagemin=>"1079",
           :herokd=>"2.23:1" },
         { :heroname=>"Lúcio", :winrate=>"57.6%", :damagemin=>"328",
           :herokd=>"1.51:1" },
         { :heroname=>"Mei", :winrate=>"51%", :damagemin=>"451",
           :herokd=>"1.95:1" },
         { :heroname=>"Reinhardt", :winrate=>"51.3%", :damagemin=>"463",
           :herokd=>"1.28:1"}
        ]

array.sort { |g,h| h[:damagemin].to_i <=> g[:damagemin].to_i }
  #=> [{ :heroname=>"Bastion", :winrate=>"53.6%", :damagemin=>"1079",
  #      :herokd=>"2.23:1"},
  #    { :heroname=>"Reinhardt", :winrate=>"51.3%", :damagemin=>"463",
  #      :herokd=>"1.28:1"},
  #    { :heroname=>"Mei", :winrate=>"51%", :damagemin=>"451",
  #      :herokd=>"1.95:1"},
  #    { :heroname=>"Lúcio", :winrate=>"57.6%", :damagemin=>"328",
  #      :herokd=>"1.51:1"}
  #   ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Cary!